# What is the fastest way to seed 1m records?

Tags: laravel

What would be the fastest way using as less as possible memory to seed 1M records in Laravel?

```
   for( $i=0; $i<1000; $i++){
        User::factory()->count(1000)->make();
    }
```

Or using chunk method or everytime the loop has 1000 records make the records and empty the variable? Or are there any other ways this could be done faster?

Comment: Since you want it fast, the higher the number here: `User::factory()->count(1000)->make();`, the faster it is. The question is how much memory can the machine can handle.

Comment: ok i reformat my question to using as little memory as possible

Comment: You mean the efficient way,  you want to balance resources and speed? I think your code should suffice

Comment: as less memory as possible: dont chunk at all and do it 1 at a time

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent models give a significant overhead. Laravel factories are a nice pattern to get some data in your database, but you will notice a slow-down for 1000s of models, since each of the models first get constructed from the PHP class (and if you would persist the factory models using `->create()` instead of `->make()`, it sends out a bunch of `creating/created/saving/saved` events as well). So the most performant way forward is to not use the factory code but instead use simple DB statements like so:

```php
$data = [['username' => 'foo', ...], ['username' => 'bar', ...]];
Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('users')->insert($data);
```

At a certain `$data` size you could run into an SQL prepared statement placeholder limit, which basically means the query is becoming too big. In that case, you can also just chunk the code above to:

```php
// Use `collect()` to create a Collection object (glorified array)
// which can chunk/paginate the data:
collect($data)->chunk(100)->each(function($chunk) {
    DB::table('users')->insert($chunk);
});
```

That being said, the Laravel factories are not bad to use and they are very handy in testing.